# Fedena translation_missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedena

My `Fedena` Installed correctly, working fine but the top search box showing this as placeholder

> en, autosuggest_menu, search_actions_links_and_people

and the inspect element in chrome is below.

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input" id="autosuggest_menu_input" name="autosuggest_menu" placeholder="<span class=&quot;translation_missing&quot;>en, autosuggest_menu, search_actions_links_and_people</span>" value="" type="text">
```

I dont see this error when I install it on my `VPS`, but when I install it at home on `ubuntu 12.04 Desktop` then I see this error.

Gem list is 100% the same.
Pls help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was because of corrupt files. Once I replaced the copy of fedena it worked like charm.